# android 8 startActivity error createchooser

Tags: android, start-activity

My app is ok until Android 7.1

On Android 8, an exception comes when I startActivity on an Intent on createchooser to open the mailing apps.

The debug is ok until :

```
Intent chooserIntent =Intent.createChooser(email, "Envoi mail...");
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

I can not find why and how.

Exception:

```
catch (InvocationTargetException e) { 
    throw new IllegalStateException( "Could not execute method for android:onClick", e);
}
```

Comment: What's the exception you're seeing?

Comment: catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Could not execute method for android:onClick", e);